# Magento 1.9 - Customer placed the order successfully but its not in the Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order

I am facing a very serious issue with Magento 1.9 website. This has happened a couple of times. Customer places the order, they even get an email confirming the order but the order does not show in the Magento admin panel.

Could you please help shade some light as to what could have caused this?

Thanks

Comment: did you check if the order is in the database?

Comment: @HelgeB I can see the order in the sales_flat_quote table in the database but that's it, what do i do?
Or what could have happened?

Comment: The order must be in `sales_flat_order` table and if everything works correctly in `sales_flat_order_grid` too. If you have the order only in `sales_flat_order` and not in `sales_flat_order_grid` the approach proposed by @Sohel Rana should work for new orders (although you should identify the problem!). For ald orders you can copy orders from `sales_flat_order` to `sales_flat_order_grid` using SQL. If you don't have the orders in `sales_flat_order` it looks like a greater problem in your store.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check, any custom extension blocks your order to save grid. Also, you can add the following event:

```
<sales_order_save_after>
    <observers>
        <sr_sales_order_save_after>
            <class>sr_magentocommunity/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderSaveAfter</method>
        </sr_sales_order_save_after>
    </observers>
</sales_order_save_after>
```

add the following code in your observer

```
/**
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function salesOrderSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if($order && ($orderId = $order->getId())) {
        Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getResource()->updateGridRecords([$orderId]);
    }
}
```